# Create directory when it does not exist

Tags: ocaml, mkdir, sys

I want to create a new directory if it doesn't exist already.
Tried several things, sadly I didn't find something in the `Sys` Library.

The nearest solution I got was:
`if not (Sys.is_directory "vegetables") then Sys.mkdir "vegetabels"`

Which obviously doesn't work since an exception is thrown. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check using `file_exists`, which is the best approach, but it's also helpful to know how to handle exceptions.

Please note `mkdir` requires a permissions value. I'll use `777` for the sake of full permissions, but in practice this is probably a bad idea.

```
try 
  if not (Sys.is_directory "vegetables") then 
    Sys.mkdir "vegetabels" 777
with Sys_error _ ->
  Sys.mkdir "vegetabels" 777
```

Alternatively, `Sys.mkdir` raises an exception if the directory or file already exists, so we can try to create the directory, and handle that exception by doing nothing.

```
try
  Sys.mkdir "vegetabels" 777
with Sys_error _ -> ()
```

Note: when you use exception handling, it's not an excuse to forget about type-checking. The type of the body of your `try` needs to have the same type as any `with` clauses. Since `Sys.mkdir` returns `unit` if successful, the exception handling clause needs to do the same.

Comment: Is it possible to create a file right afterwards. I always get ```Sys_error "vegetables/apple.txt: Permission Denied"```. Only when I restart the program ```apple.txt``` is created. Already tried it with 777 - still not allowed

Comment: @col.ulb: Both in your original question and in this answer `vegetables` is spelt incorrectly. Make sure you always spell it the same way.

Comment: As a tiny nit, using mkdir and handling the error if it already exists avoids the time-of-check to time-of-use race. Perhaps it's not a concern for this particular application, but it's good hygiene to avoid it in general.

Comment: The constant above should be octal, not decimal: `0o777`.

Answer (score 7):

You missed `Sys.file_exists` (directories are considered to be files in unix-like systems):

```
let create_newdir path perm =
  if not (Sys.file_exists path) then Sys.mkdir path perm
```